# Why might be the problem of my pipelines? Pipeline runs but no resources deployed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, cicd

I just wanted to test how this is supposed to work. So the function in question is just the basic HTTP trigger template from visual studio and pushed to devops repo, the function app is manually made via portal, and I am using classic editor to make my pipelines

So I first build it

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build project'
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--output publish_output --configuration Release'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output'
    includeRootFolder: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
```

and then use the artifact for the release pipeline

```
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.AzureSubscription’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.AppType’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.AppName’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972

steps:
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  displayName: 'Deploy Azure Function App'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(Parameters.AzureSubscription)'
    appType: '$(Parameters.AppType)'
    appName: '$(Parameters.AppName)'
    package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_testcase1-Azure Functions for .NET-CI/drop'
```

These are the generated YAML so yes I have the subscription, app type, and app name filled in. But anyway here's the classic editor if that say anything more.

To build artifact:
[image: build][image: archive][image]

To release:
[image]

The thing is, both pipeline runs perfectly fine, they give green light claiming to be successful. It's just that I don't end up with a function in my function app. I have manually uploaded my function from visual studio, using a publishing profile, and then I run this pipeline, it effectively removes the function that I have manually published. I'm guessing there's something wrong with my artifact? That's why it's deploying absolutely nothing, and that's why it removes any existing functions on my app? What else might be the problem here?

Comment: You could check the artifact by yourself, since you have already published as artifact. Just check the images you provided, I do not think there is any issue for the pipeline configuration, to do more research, you may need provide the build log and deploy log.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT [Build log](https://textsharing.com/523/) and [release](http://textsharing.com/522/). I'm not too sure on how to "check the artifact" myself, it's a zip file, what am I supposed to see in there?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Okay I've deployed the zip file from azure cli and it made it to the function app perfectly good. The artifact is fine, it has to be my pipelines then? But the release pipeline seems to be okay, it starts the job and tries to download the zip, then deploy the zip. What else would be the problem here?

Comment: @maybemonday when you do a normal publish to zip, that same folder structure should be published by your pipeline. In my case the, the Root Folder or file to Archive had to be updated to $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\bin\Release\net6.0, your's would be relative to what core version you're using. So check the artifact zip file till you see the net3.1/net6.0 etc folder and update your path. See if that helps.